# Trying to Configure NGINX as Reverse Proxy for RocketChat

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to configure NGINX as reverse proxy to use the RocketChat Service but the service is not loading on the desired location. The in port is 2357 at which the service(RocketChat) is running and the out port on which it should run is port 3000. Can anyone help me out with this?
[Code for the location on which RocketChat should load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBaDW.png)

I am also adding the docker-compose image infrastructure for reference.
[Docker Image Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtgwM.png)

nginx.conf file :

```
    location ^~ /chat {
  client_max_body_size 200m;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
  proxy_redirect off;
  
  proxy_pass http://rocketchat:3000/;
}
```

docker-compose-org.yml:

```
    # Image--infrastructure:rocketchat
  rocketchat:
    image: rocketchat/rocket.chat:latest
    hostname: rocketchat
    command: >
      bash -c
        "for i in `seq 1 30`; do
          node main.js &&
          s=$$? && break || s=$$?;
          echo \"Tried $$i times. Waiting 5 secs...\";
          sleep 5;
        done; (exit $$s)"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - nodelocal
      - nodelocal-private
    ports:
      - 2357:3000
    volumes:
      - ./data/rocketchat/app/uploads:/app/uploads
    environment:
      PORT: 3000
      ROOT_URL: http://localhost:3000
      MONGO_URL: mongodb://mongo:27017/rocketchat
      MONGO_OPLOG_URL: mongodb://mongo:27017/local
      MAIL_URL: smtp://smtp.email
      # HTTP_PROXY: 'http://rocketchat.cdli.com'
      # HTTPS_PROXY: 'http://rocketchat.cdli.com'
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=rocketchat"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host: rocketchat.cdli.com"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
```

RocketChat Container Logs:

```
LocalStore: store created at 

LocalStore: store created at 

LocalStore: store created at 

{"level":40,"time":"2022-04-27T05:00:03.411Z","pid":10,"hostname":"rocketchat","name":"","name":"VoIPService","msg":"Voip is not enabled. Cant start the service"}

{"level":51,"time":"2022-04-27T05:00:03.855Z","pid":10,"hostname":"rocketchat","name":"","name":"Migrations","msg":"Not migrating, already at version 256"}

ufs: temp directory created at "/tmp/ufs"

Loaded the Apps Framework and loaded a total of 0 Apps!

+----------------------------------------------+

|                SERVER RUNNING                |

+----------------------------------------------+

|                                              |

|  Rocket.Chat Version: 4.5.0                  |

|       NodeJS Version: 14.18.3 - x64          |

|      MongoDB Version: 4.0.28                 |

|       MongoDB Engine: mmapv1                 |

|             Platform: linux                  |

|         Process Port: 3000                   |

|             Site URL: http://localhost:3000  |

|     ReplicaSet OpLog: Enabled                |

|          Commit Hash: 3901054684             |

|        Commit Branch: HEAD                   |

|                                              |

+----------------------------------------------+

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

|                              DEPRECATION                             |

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

|                                                                      |

|  YOUR CURRENT MONGODB VERSION (4.0.28) IS DEPRECATED.                |

|  IT WILL NOT BE SUPPORTED ON ROCKET.CHAT VERSION 5.0.0 AND GREATER,  |

|  PLEASE UPGRADE MONGODB TO VERSION 4.2 OR GREATER                    |

|                                                                      |

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

LocalStore: store created at 

LocalStore: store created at 

LocalStore: store created at 

{"level":40,"time":"2022-05-01T09:58:08.360Z","pid":10,"hostname":"rocketchat","name":"","name":"VoIPService","msg":"Voip is not enabled. Cant start the service"}

{"level":51,"time":"2022-05-01T09:58:08.797Z","pid":10,"hostname":"rocketchat","name":"","name":"Migrations","msg":"Not migrating, already at version 256"}

Loaded the Apps Framework and loaded a total of 0 Apps!

+----------------------------------------------+

|                SERVER RUNNING                |

+----------------------------------------------+

|                                              |

|  Rocket.Chat Version: 4.5.0                  |

|       NodeJS Version: 14.18.3 - x64          |

|      MongoDB Version: 4.0.28                 |

|       MongoDB Engine: mmapv1                 |

|             Platform: linux                  |

|         Process Port: 3000                   |

|             Site URL: http://localhost:3000  |

|     ReplicaSet OpLog: Enabled                |

|          Commit Hash: 3901054684             |

|        Commit Branch: HEAD                   |

|                                              |

+----------------------------------------------+

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

|                              DEPRECATION                             |

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+

|                                                                      |

|  YOUR CURRENT MONGODB VERSION (4.0.28) IS DEPRECATED.                |

|  IT WILL NOT BE SUPPORTED ON ROCKET.CHAT VERSION 5.0.0 AND GREATER,  |

|  PLEASE UPGRADE MONGODB TO VERSION 4.2 OR GREATER                    |

|                                                                      |

+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I believe I can help. But first please provide all configuration scripts as code snippets (and not as screenshots). so that we can use copy/paste easily. This is also part of the Stackoverflow etiquette. Thanks

Comment: Sure. Sorry for not sharing the files, actually, it's the first time I am posting a question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: No worries. Just edit the question before someone flags the question as "low quality" :-)

Comment: Is NGINX also defined as a service in the docker-compose file? or is it running as a service on the host machine?

Comment: Nginx is also defined as a service in docker-compose file.

Answer (score 1):

NGINX is receiving http/https requests and the proxy configuration should pass those requests to the host and port on which rocketchat is listening.

In your docker-compose.yaml file, you specify the rocketchat service and map port 2357 on the host machine to port 3000 in the container.

So which that said, if NGINX is running on the host machine as a linux service (not as part of the docker-compose file) then you need to edit the last line of the NGINX configuration for the location to point to localhost:2357:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:2357
```

look at my blog posts regarding hosting and managing Rocket.Chat using docker-compose... here:

https://blog.jarrousse.org/2022/04/09/an-elegant-way-to-use-docker-compose-to-obtain-and-renew-a-lets-encrypt-ssl-certificate-with-certbot-and-configure-the-nginx-service-to-use-it/

here:

https://blog.jarrousse.org/2022/04/26/using-docker-compose-in-to-deploy-rocket-chat/

and here:

https://blog.jarrousse.org/2022/08/01/migrate-a-self-hosted-manual-deployment-of-rocket-chat-to-a-deployment-based-on-docker-compose-without-losing-data/

Comment: So? did it work? If my answer helped, you can mark it as correct (that will give me points) you could also up-vote it (that will give me more points).

Comment: I tried what you said above, but the page is not loading and I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway request error.

Comment: Could you provide the log of the rocketchat container? I suspect that the rocketchat service is not working properly

Comment: I have added all the required code along with the logs of the rocketchat container. Ptal!! Thanks!

Comment: Thumbs up. Any progress with your problem?

Comment: I wrote a blog post to a configurations that works for me. Maybe if you try it out you could  issue could be resolved: https://blog.jarrousse.org/using-docker-compose-in-to-deploy-rocket-chat/ you could also take a look at my previous post: https://blog.jarrousse.org/an-elegant-way-to-use-docker-compose-to-obtain-and-renew-a-lets-encrypt-ssl-certificate-with-certbot-and-configure-the-nginx-service-to-use-it/